# Finding the shortest path in a graph with teleports

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph

I have this graph problem I'm not sure how to approach.

I have an undirected graph with N vertices numbered `1`-`N`. Every vertex numbered `i` has an arbitrary "rank" that can be anywhere from `1`-`i`. Multiple vertices can have the same rank.

When traversing the graph, any vertex with rank `r` can instantly teleport/traverse to another vertex with the same rank `r`. This means unconnected components are still "connected" if at least one vertex from component A has the same rank as a vertex from component B.

How do I calculate the minimum amount of vertices needed to traverse from vertex A to vertex B?

---

My very naive solution is to add every edge that connects every equal-ranked vertex together to the graph, then applying a standard path-finding algorithm. This has a ridiculously long time complexity but I can't figure out a more efficient way to solve this.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

adding all edges between same rank nodes is too slow as you have noticed - in worst case as close to all nodes are same rank it goes to `O(n^2)`

A way to solve this is to introduce new nodes for each rank and connect all nodes of same rank to one of new nodes (i.e. for nodes with rank 1 connect to node n+1 and so on).

Then you can consider new nodes to be of weight 0 when traversing to them - that way you can simply do 0-1 BFS with a dequeue (adding 0 weight nodes to front and other ones to the end once encountered) - this is linear so its solve-able in `O(n)`